# How to write json variable in Datatables (My data is not displayed)

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, datatables

This is my Model Class below

```
public class VisibleBodyAccessCodes
{
    [Key]
    public int VISIBLE_BODY_ACCESS_CODESId { get; set; }


    public string ACTIVATION_CODE { get; set; }


    public string STAR_ID { get; set; }


    public string FIRST_NAME { get; set; }


}
```

And this is my api call in controllers

```
[HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetAssignedCodeUsers()
    {
        var records = _context.VISIBLE_BODY_ACCESS_CODES.ToList();
        
        return new JsonResult(records);
    }
```

When I put the debugger in the var records, I can see the records.
This is my datatables call

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {  
   var table = $("#DT_load").DataTable({  
         
      ajax: {
                "url": "/VisibleBodyAccessCodes/GetAssignedCodeUsers",              
                "type": "GET",
                "dataSrc": "",
                "datatype": "json"
      },
        columns: [
           
            { "data": "FIRST_NAME"}
        ]
    });  
});
```

Below is my html

```
    <table id="DT_load" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                @*<th>code</th>*@
                <th>name</th>
                
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The problem I got that the data are not displayed in the table for me.
I got an error that said
"DataTables warning: table id=DT_load - Requested unknown parameter 'FIRST_NAME' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see [http://datatables.net/tn/4"](http://datatables.net/tn/4%22)

If you could point me to the right direction, thanks!

Comment: with out thinking about the code, I have one question, do you want to show single object or a list of objects?

Comment: a list of objects

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `FIRST_NAME` to `First_Name` in VisibleBodyAccessCodes:

```
public class VisibleBodyAccessCodes
{
    ...

    public string First_Name{ get; set; }


}
```

And then change `FIRST_NAME` to `first_Name` in `column`:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {  
   var table = $("#DT_load").DataTable({  
         
      ajax: {
                "url": "/VisibleBodyAccessCodes/GetAssignedCodeUsers",              
                "type": "GET",
                "dataSrc": "",
                "datatype": "json"
      },
        columns: [
           
            { "data": "first_Name"}
        ]
    });  
});
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you @Yiyi. the problem is I can not change the Model class properties that the database developer created. If there is another way to do this would be better for me.

Comment: I found the solution: I added this using System.Text.Json.Serialization; to my model class and added attribute on top of my property  [JsonPropertyName("FirstName")] public string FIRST_NAME { get; set; }

Comment: and the name of {"data": "FirstName"} need to be the same as the JsonPropertyName in the model class